# FeignClient specified configuration class does not take effect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-loadbalancer, nacos

I'm a novice at Stack Overflow. I really don't know why 'Ask Question' doesn't indicate the location to be formatted. I can only use Blackquote to wrap most non code segments. Maybe Stack Overflow can make questions friendly?

> I use **[Nacos](https://nacos.io)** service registration, use **Spring LoadBalancer**
> to initiate remote calls with openfeign, I specify a configuration
> class to specify log output level and load balancing strategy for
> **FeignClient**.
>
> I extracted FeignClient and Configuration into separate module commons

```java
// FeignClient Configuration
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("at999.cloud.commons.feign")
public class FeignConfig{

    private String logging;
    private String rule;

    @Bean
    public Logger.Level level(){
        System.out.println(">> " + logging + " >>");
        switch(String.valueOf(logging)){
            case "FULL":
                return Logger.Level.FULL;
            case "HEADERS":
                return Logger.Level.HEADERS;
            case "BASIC":
                return Logger.Level.BASIC;
            case "NONE":
            case "null":
            default:
                return Logger.Level.NONE;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactorServiceInstanceLoadBalancer rule(Environment evnt,
            LoadBalancerClientFactory lbcf, NacosDiscoveryProperties ndps)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
                          NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException{
        System.out.println(">>> " + rule + " >>>");
        if(rule != null){
            Class.forName(rule).asSubclass(ReactorServiceInstanceLoadBalancer.class);
            String pn = LoadBalancerClientFactory.getName(evnt);
            System.out.println("*** " + pn + " ***");
            ObjectProvider<ServiceInstanceListSupplier> op = lbcf.getLazyProvider(pn, ServiceInstanceListSupplier.class);
            if(rule.endsWith(".NacosLoadBalancer"))
                return new NacosLoadBalancer(op, pn, ndps);
            else{
                Object or = Class.forName(rule).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(op, pn);
                if(or instanceof ReactorServiceInstanceLoadBalancer){
                    return ReactorServiceInstanceLoadBalancer.class.cast(or);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

> bootstrap.yml

```yaml
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /

spring:
  application:
    name: nacos-client
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    nacos:
      config:
        server-addr: at999.eu.org:8848
        file-extension: yaml
      discovery:
        # I use a remote server to run the registry
        server-addr: at999.eu.org:8848
        # I want to use NacosRule to give preference to local cluster
        # I have also deployed the same cluster on the remote server
        cluster-name: CN
        username: nacos
        password: nacos
```

> [NacosRule](https://github.com/alibaba/spring-cloud-alibaba/blob/2021.x/spring-cloud-alibaba-starters/spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery/src/main/java/com/alibaba/cloud/nacos/loadbalancer/NacosLoadBalancer.java)
>
> The same configuration for the service provider
>
> just no content of application.yml and bootstrap.yml cluster-name is
> US and application.name is user-client

> application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enabled: false

loadbalancer:
  client:
    name: ${spring.application.name}

at999:
  cloud:
    commons:
      feign:
        logging: FULL
        rule: com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.loadbalancer.NacosLoadBalancer
```

> Specify configuration properties

```
// Feign Client
@FeignClient(value="user-client", configuration=FeignConfig.class)
public interface UserClientFeign{

    @GetMapping("/user")
    User getUser();

}
```

> This is the service provider

```java
@GetMapping("/user")
public User getUser(){
    user.setName(user.getName() + "(c)");
    return user;
}
```

> This is the consumer of the service

```java
@Resource
private UserClientFeign userClientFeign;

@GetMapping("/get/user")
public User getUserServiceUser(){
    return userClientFeign.getUser();
}
```

> Consumers import commons modules
>
> commons module spring.factories

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
                                                               \
com.at999.springcloud.nacos.commons.FeignConfiguration
```

> Scanning doesn't seem to work

```java
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.at999.springcloud.nacos.commons.feign.config")
public class FeignConfiguration{

}
```

> This is the commons directory structure

```bash
$tree
.
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── at999
│   │           └── springcloud
│   │               └── nacos
│   │                   └── commons
│   │                       ├── FeignConfiguration.java
│   │                       ├── feign
│   │                       │   ├── UserClientFeign.java
│   │                       │   └── config
│   │                       │       └── FeignConfig.java
│   │                       │
│   │                       └── pojo
│   │                           └── User.java
```

> consumer main startup class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients(clients=UserClientFeign.class)
public class ApplicationStart{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStart.class, args);
    }

}
```

> access interface
>
> The first access succeeded because it used the default polling

```bash
$curl http://localhost:8080/get/user
```

```
[ERROR] 2022-10-21 00:30:48,730 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-3 ~ org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] ~ ?.?:? -- Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.RetryableException: Connect timed out executing GET http://user-client/user] with root cause
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:543)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:594)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:373)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
    at feign.Client$Default.convertResponse(Client.java:109)
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:105)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerUtils.executeWithLoadBalancerLifecycleProcessing(LoadBalancerUtils.java:56)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerUtils.executeWithLoadBalancerLifecycleProcessing(LoadBalancerUtils.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:113)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy85.getUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.at999.springcloud.nacos.client.controller.TestController.getUserServiceUser(TestController.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:485)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at com.at999.springcloud.nacos.client.controller.TestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$beda0af8.getUserServiceUser(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at 
    ...
```

> I searched for a day and couldn't find a solution, GitHub traced some
> source code, but without IDEA debugging, the laptop (a dozen years
> ago) can only run light linux
>
> I have tried removing FeignConfig's annotation @Configuration
>
> The access interface will only appear 404
>
> FeignClient does not resolve to an accessible ip:port after pulling
> the service for the first time

```bash
$curl http://localhost:8080/get/user
```

```
[INFO] 2022-10-21 01:04:26,149 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-1 ~ org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] ~ ?.?:? -- Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[INFO] 2022-10-21 01:04:26,149 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-1 ~ org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet ~ ?.?:? -- Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[INFO] 2022-10-21 01:04:26,152 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-1 ~ org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet ~ ?.?:? -- Completed initialization in 3 ms
[INFO] 2022-10-21 01:04:26,697 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-1 ~ com.alibaba.nacos.client.naming ~ ?.?:? -- new ips(2) service: DEFAULT\_GROUP@@nacos-client -> [{"instanceId":"192.168.1.39#8080#CN#DEFAULT\_GROUP@@nacos-client","ip":"192.168.1.39","port":8080,"weight":1.0,"healthy":true,"enabled":true,"ephemeral":true,"clusterName":"CN","serviceName":"DEFAULT\_GROUP@@nacos-client","metadata":{"preserved.register.source":"SPRING\_CLOUD"},"ipDeleteTimeout":30000,"instanceHeartBeatInterval":5000,"instanceHeartBeatTimeOut":15000},{"instanceId":"172.16.0.15#8080#US#DEFAULT\_GROUP@@nacos-client","ip":"172.16.0.15","port":8080,"weight":1.0,"healthy":true,"enabled":true,"ephemeral":true,"clusterName":"US","serviceName":"DEFAULT\_GROUP@@nacos-client","metadata":{"preserved.register.source":"SPRING\_CLOUD"},"ipDeleteTimeout":30000,"instanceHeartBeatInterval":5000,"instanceHeartBeatTimeOut":15000}]
[INFO] 2022-10-21 01:04:26,720 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-1 ~ com.alibaba.nacos.client.naming ~ ?.?:? -- current ips:(2) service: DEFAULT\_GROUP@@nacos-client -> [{"instanceId":"192.168.1.39#8080#CN#DEFAULT\_GROUP@@nacos-client","ip":"192.168.1.39","port":8080,"weight":1.0,"healthy":true,"enabled":true,"ephemeral":true,"clusterName":"CN","serviceName":"DEFAULT\_GROUP@@nacos-client","metadata":{"preserved.register.source":"SPRING\_CLOUD"},"ipDeleteTimeout":30000,"instanceHeartBeatInterval":5000,"instanceHeartBeatTimeOut":15000},{"instanceId":"172.16.0.15#8080#US#DEFAULT\_GROUP@@nacos-client","ip":"172.16.0.15","port":8080,"weight":1.0,"healthy":true,"enabled":true,"ephemeral":true,"clusterName":"US","serviceName":"DEFAULT\_GROUP@@nacos-client","metadata":{"preserved.register.source":"SPRING\_CLOUD"},"ipDeleteTimeout":30000,"instanceHeartBeatInterval":5000,"instanceHeartBeatTimeOut":15000}]
[ERROR] 2022-10-21 01:04:27,034 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-1 ~ org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] ~ ?.?:? -- Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException$NotFound: [404] during [GET] to [http://user-client/user] [UserClientFeign#getUser()]: [{"timestamp":"2022-10-20T17:04:26.853+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/user"}]] with root cause
feign.FeignException$NotFound: [404] during [GET] to [http://user-client/user] [UserClientFeign#getUser()]: [{"timestamp":"2022-10-20T17:04:26.853+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/user"}]
    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:219)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:194)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:185)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92)
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy85.getUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.at999.springcloud.nacos.client.controller.TestController.getUserServiceUser(TestController.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:485)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at com.at999.springcloud.nacos.client.controller.TestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c1eb0cb4.getUserServiceUser(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
{"timestamp":"2022-10-20T17:04:27.038+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","path":"/get/user"}⏎
```

> I tried to delete the loadbalancer.client.name attribute in
> application.yml, so that the  Bean rule in FeignConfig cannot get the
> name value when creating NacosLoadBalancer at startup
>
> Accessing the interface he will have the following error

```bash
$curl http://localhost:8080/get/user
```

```
[INFO] 2022-10-21 01:25:33,098 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-1 ~ org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] ~ ?.?:? -- Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[INFO] 2022-10-21 01:25:33,098 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-1 ~ org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet ~ ?.?:? -- Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[INFO] 2022-10-21 01:25:33,104 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-1 ~ org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet ~ ?.?:? -- Completed initialization in 6 ms
[ERROR] 2022-10-21 01:25:33,871 ~ http-nio-8080-exec-1 ~ org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] ~ ?.?:? -- Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.hashCode()" because "key" is null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.hashCode()" because "key" is null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:964)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getProvider(NamedContextFactory.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.ClientFactoryObjectProvider.delegate(ClientFactoryObjectProvider.java:115)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.ClientFactoryObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(ClientFactoryObjectProvider.java:64)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.loadbalancer.NacosLoadBalancer.choose(NacosLoadBalancer.java:68)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.loadbalancer.NacosLoadBalancer.choose(NacosLoadBalancer.java:47)
    at org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.blocking.client.BlockingLoadBalancerClient.choose(BlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:155)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:97)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy85.getUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.at999.springcloud.nacos.client.controller.TestController.getUserServiceUser(TestController.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:485)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at com.at999.springcloud.nacos.client.controller.TestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88a31f37.getUserServiceUser(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
{"timestamp":"2022-10-20T17:25:34.013+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","path":"/get/user"}⏎
```

I know that in `spring.cloud.nacos.loadbalancer.enabled=true` it will use NacosRule

I just want to know where I went wrong

Comment: The configuration passed via `@FeignClient` annotation should only contain config for the actual Feign client, such as `feign.Encoder`, `feign.Decoder`, `feign.Contract`. See docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults). LB configuration should be passed via `@LoadBalancerClient`.